# Convert vector to owned array without copying

Tags: c++

A `std::vector` is more or less this:

```cpp
class vector {
   T* array;
   size_t length;
   size_t capacity;
public:
   ...
}
```

Is it possible to extract the `array` object, taking ownership of it without copying any data? In other words, so that this is a valid program with no undefined behaviour or memory leaks.

```cpp
int main() {
  vector<int> foo = {1, 2, 3};
  int* fooArray = foo.magical_extraction_method();
  delete[] fooArray;
}
```

To be clear, I am *not* looking for `foo.data()`, `&foo[0]` or similar. I want ownership of the underlying array.

Comment: Why would you want something like that? Is it plain curiosity (which is okay, but should be stated) or is there an underlying problem that you want to solve?

Comment: Why don't you simply take ownership of the vector instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've read about people encountering a case where they use one bad library that insists on returning a vector, and another bad library that insists on taking ownership of a pointer. This would be useful in such situation as it would allow avoiding copying while still using both libraries.

Comment: You might be able to hack this using a custom allocator, but .. don't.

Comment: @eerorika you may have underestimated the issue. Libraries which take ownership of a pointer usually give you a specific way to allocate the buffer. If the copy is really expensive, consider changing libraries.

Comment: @pqnet well designed libraries do. According to the programmer who described the issue, that was not the case. Changing libraries would be ideal choice for performance; not for dev time though.

Comment: @eerorika I can't make the best choices for them as I don't know what their goal are, I can only make them aware of the possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to extract the array object, taking ownership of it

No, there is no standard way to extract ownership from a `std::vector`. Except into another vector (using move).

> ```
> delete[] fooArray;
> ```

`delete[]` is only allowed on a pointer returned by `new[]`. A `std::vector` never owns such pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter:

```
template<class T>
struct VectorDeleter {
    explicit constexpr VectorDeleter(std::vector<T> v) noexcept : v{std::move(v)} {};
    VectorDeleter(VectorDeleter&&) = default;
    VectorDeleter& operator=(VectorDeleter const&) = delete;
    std::vector<T> v;
    void operator()(T* p) {
        assert(p == v.data());
        v.clear();
    }
};

template<class T>
std::unique_ptr<T[], VectorDeleter<T>> release(std::vector<T>&& v) {
    auto const p = v.data();
    return std::unique_ptr<T[], VectorDeleter<T>>{p, VectorDeleter<T>{std::move(v)}};
}
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/nM5YKK).

There is nothing in the standard that can manage the memory of a `std::vector` other than the same `std::vector`. Mostly, this is because any number of elements from 0 to `capacity()` may have been constructed, and these elements only must be destructed before freeing the memory.